# How to determine the injectivity, surjectivity, and bijectivity of given linear transformations in mathematics?

Tags: linear-algebra

Sorry for the beginner's question! For example, I have three linear maps:

$f_1(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
4 & 5 & 6
\end{pmatrix}x$

$f_2(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
-1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}x$

$f_3(x) = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 4 \\
2 & 5 \\
3 & 6 
\end{pmatrix}x$

How can I check which matrix is surjective, injective or both (bijective)?

I know that $f_1$ couldn't be injective because the rank of it $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3\\
0 & -3 & -6
\end{pmatrix}$ is 2 < # cols. But it's equal to #lines, so it must be surjective.

I think that $f_2$ is bijective because the rank of it is 2 which is equal to # cols and # lines.

I think that $f_3$ is injective too because the rank $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 4 \\ 0 & -3 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ of it is 2 which is equal to # cols but it isn't to # lines.

So is it true, that $f_1$ is surjective, $f_2$ is bijective and $f_3$ is injective? And is the justification sufficient?

Comment: Write down the definition of injectivity and surjectivity first. Whenever you want to prove something, this is always the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following basic properties help:$\newcommand{\r}{\mathbb{R}}\newcommand{\rank}{\text{rank}}$

> Let $V$ and $W$ be finite dimensional vector spaces. Let $f:V\to W$ be a linear map.
> Then
>
> 1. The image of $f$ is equal to the column space of $f$.
> 2. $\rank(f)\le \max(\dim(V),\dim(W))$.
> 3. If $f$ is injective, then $\dim(V)\le \dim(W)$.
> 4. If $f$ is surjective, then $\dim(V)\ge \dim(W)$.
> 5. If $f$ is bijective, then $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$.
> 6. If $\dim(V)=\dim(W)$, then $f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective.
> 7. $\ker(f)=\{0\}$ iff $\rank(f)=\dim(V)$ iff $f$ is injective.

Also, if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\dim(U)=\dim(V)<\infty$, then $U=V$.
All these can be proved by considering the basis of the spaces or by rank-nullity theorem.

You can write out explicitly the domains and codomains of the linear maps in question and analyze their dimensions to help you out.
We have $f_1:\r^3\to\r^2$, $f_2:\r^2\to\r^2$, $f_3:\r^2\to\r^3$.

As you have shown, $\rank(f_1)=2$, so the image of $f_1$ is a subspace of $\r^2$ that has dimension $2$ and must be equal to $\r^2$.
Since the image of $f_1$ is its codomain, $f_1$ is surjective.
We cannot have the injectivity of $f_1$ because $\dim(\r^3)>\dim(\r^2)$ (using property 3 above).

Since $\rank(f_2)=\dim(\r^2)$,
the map $f_2$ must be surjective by a similar reason as in the previous paragraph.
Then property 6 guarantees that $f_2$ is also injective and thus bijective.

Using property 4, we know that $f_3$ cannot be surjective.
Since $\rank(f_3)=\dim(\r^2)$, the map $f_3$ is injective by property 7.
Alternative, you can consider the map $g:\r^2\to f_3(\r^2)$ defined by $g(x)=f_3(x)$ for all $x\in\r^2$,
and show that $g$ is surjective, which implies that $g$ is injective by property 6,
which then implies the injectivity of $f_3$.

Comment: thank you for the more detailed reasoning! <3